# Operator overloading through inheritance causes ambiguity

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, operator-overloading

I am writing some template library (lets say a linear algebra library) and got the next complicated bug, that I am able to reproduce only on GCC (Clang and VC++ work as expected).

The library consists of generic template types like

```
template<class C, int N>
class Vector;
template<class C, int N, int M = N>
class Matrix;
```

with some default implementations those are not used.
Also there are a set of interface classes like these

```
template<class C, int N>
struct VecMulInterface
{
    Vector<C, N> operator*(const Vector<C, N>& v)
    {
        return static_cast<Matrix<C, N, N>*>(this)->mul_impl(v);
    }
};

template<class C, int N>
struct ScalMulInterface
{
    Matrix<C, N, N> operator*(const C& c)
    {
        return static_cast<Matrix<C, N, N>*>(this)->mul_impl(c);
    }
};
```

and respective implementations providers

```
template<class C, int N>
struct MulImpl
{
public:
    Vector<C, N> mul_impl(const Vector<C, N>& v) const
    {        
        return {}; // imagine some logic here
    }
    Matrix<C, N, N> mul_impl(const C& c) const
    {     
        return {}; // imagine some logic here
    }
};
```

Finally I have template specializations those use everything from above:

```
template<class C>
class Vector<C, 2>
{
public:
    C items[2];
    // ...
};

template<class C>
class Matrix<C, 2, 2>:
    public VecMulInterface<C, 2>,
    public ScalMulInterface<C, 2>,
    public MulImpl<C, 2>
{
public:
    C items[4];
    // ...
};
```

I try to use them like this:

```
Matrix<int, 2, 2> m;
Vector<int, 2> v1, v2;
v2 = m * v1; // <- error
```

Now the GCC spawns an error "error: request for member ‘operator*’ is ambiguous".
But! 
If I change the line with error such that I use overloaded function instead of 'operator*'

```
v2 = m.mul_impl( v1 ); // <- NO error
```

OR if instead of inheriting from respective interfaces I place the operators out-of-class like this:

```
template<class C, int N>
Vector<C, N> operator*(const Matrix<C, N, N>& m, const Vector<C, N>& v)
{
    return m.mul_impl(v);
}
template<class C, int N>
Matrix<C, N, N> operator*(const Matrix<C, N, N>& m, const C& c)
{
    return m.mul_impl(c);
}
```

everything works just fine. (VC++ and Clang seems to work correctly in all cases)

Could anyone explain the reason for such behavior? Is this a compiler bug or I stepped onto "undefined behavior" somewhere in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions in different scopes don't overload.  For the member `operator*` case, the two functions are in `VecMulInterface` and `ScalMulInterface` respectively, so they are in different scopes.  In the other two cases, the two functions are in the same scope.

You can use a using declaration to promote them to the same scope:

```
template<class C>
class Matrix<C, 2, 2> :
    public VecMulInterface<C, 2>,
    public ScalMulInterface<C, 2>,
    public MulImpl<C, 2>
{
public:
    using VecMulInterface<C, 2>::operator*;
    using ScalMulInterface<C, 2>::operator*;
    // ...
};
```

A more elegant approach is to use `friend` functions in the interfaces:

```
template <class C, int N>
struct VecMulInterface
{
    friend Vector<C, N> operator*(const Matrix<C, N, N>& m, const Vector<C, N>& v)
    {
        return m.mul_impl(m, v);
    }
};
```